# Is it possible to use IN clause in plain sql Slick?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10, slick

For example, I want to create the following query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM Coffees c WHERE c.name IN ('robusta', 'arabica')
```

My attempt failed:

```
val cnames = List("robusta", "arabica")
sql""" SELECT c.* FROM Coffees c WHERE c.name IN ${cnames} """
  could not find implicit value for parameter pconv: 
  scala.slick.jdbc.SetParameter[List[String]]
```

Is it possible to somehow use `in` clause in `Slick` plain sql queries?

Comment: What puzzles me most, is that in Slick's lifted embedding, this is almost an effortless task.

Comment: I use `slick-pg` and `select * from Coffees where array_position(${cnames}, name) is not null`.

Comment: For newer versions of Slick, was also answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31156613/is-it-possible-to-use-in-clause-in-plain-sql-slick-for-integers

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The type safe "lifted embedding" API supports this as well:

```
val ids = List(1,2,3)
val q = for {
  f <- Foo if f.id inSet ids // ids is not bound
}
```

[slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.ColumnExtensionMethods](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/1.0.1/api/index.html#scala.slick.lifted.ColumnExtensionMethods)

Comment: Thanks! I was able to use this in Slick 3.0 as well: query.filter(_.id inSet ids)

Comment: How does this apply to plain SQL Slick (as is asked by the question)? I'm looking for that answer & this doesn't apply.

Comment: It doesn't apply. If you use `ids` you get `Could not find implicit value for parameter e: slick.jdbc.SetParameter[List[String]]`. Downvoting because although it works in other cases, it doesn't answer this question. Related issue: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/1335

Answer (score 4):

Although it's not safe for SQL injection, you can use `#$` interpolator:

```
val ids = idList.mkString("'", "','", "'")
val q = sql"""select name from mytable where id in (#$ids)"""
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything out of the box to handle this.  You're best bet is probably something like this:

```
val cnames = List("robusta", "arabica").mkString("'", "','", "'")
val query = sql""" SELECT c.* FROM Coffees c WHERE c.name IN (${cnames}) """
```

Comment: @Rogarch, as things have changed in slick and my answer is no longer correct, could you please change the accepted answer to the one below so I can delete this answer?

Comment: This will work if the interpolation uses #$ instead of $, but it's still very unsafe. :) http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/sql.html `scala> sqlu""" update tbl_foo set x = 1 where y in #$z """
res30: scala.slick.jdbc.StaticQuery[Unit,Int] = <function1>

scala> res30.getStatement
res31: String = " update tbl_foo set x = 1 where y in (1,2) "
` (sorry I have no idea how to format this nicely when I can't insert returns)

Comment: Not too familiar with slick, but doesn't this introduce a SQLi vulnerability? Or is it handled by the `sql` quasiquote?

Answer (score 1):

I have written a small extension to Slick that addresses exactly this problem:  https://github.com/rtkaczyk/inslick

For the given example the solution would be:

```scala
import accode.inslick.syntax._

val cnames = List("robusta", "arabica")
sqli""" SELECT c.* FROM Coffees c WHERE c.name IN *${cnames} """
```

Additionally InSlick works with iterables of tuples or case classes. It's available for all Slick 3.x versions and Scala versions 2.11 - 2.13. We've been using it in production for several months at the company I work for.

The interpolation is safe from SQL injection. It utilises a macro which rewrites the query in a way similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36561504/2464117) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library that (among other things) introduces a binder for list properties to Slick's SQL interpolator: 
https://index.scala-lang.org/tarao/slick-jdbc-extension-scala/slick-jdbc-extension

Example code from the page:

```
  import util.NonEmpty

  def findAll(entryIds: Option[NonEmpty[Long]]): Seq[Entry] = entryIds match {
    case Some(ids) => run { sql"""
    | SELECT * FROM ${table}
    | WHERE entry_id IN $ids
    """.as[Entry] }
    case None => Seq.empty
  }
```