# How to do row insert conditionally, i.e. INSERT INTO with WHERE NOT EXISTS?

Tags: scala, slick

Let's consider this table:

```
    +----------+----------+
    | user_id  | store_id |
    +----------+----------+
    |    39    |    8     |
    |    8     |    39    |
    |    5     |    11    |
    +----------+----------+
```

I mapped it with slick with (dropping indexes & foreign keys for simplifying it):

```
case class FavoriteStore(userId: Long, storeId: Long)

class FavoriteStoreTable(tag: Tag) 
     extends Table[FavoriteStore](tag, "FAVORITE_STORE") {
  def userId = column[Long]("USER_ID")
  def storeId = column[Long]("STORE_ID")
  override def * = (userId, storeId) <> 
              (FavoriteStore.tupled, FavoriteStore.unapply)
}
```

I would like to be able to write the following SQL query with Slick:

```
INSERT INTO favorite_store (user_id, store_id) VALUES (39, 8)
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM favorite_store WHERE user_id = 39 AND store_id = 8)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Slick currently does not support WHERE NOT EXISTS. Please open a feature request: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not supported by Slick and I created the following issue: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/800

Answer (score 0):

Since at least Slick 3.0.0 this is now possible with composed bind queries in Slick.

Check out this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31352126/3305586

More information on composing binded queries (gave me better understanding of what was done in the answer I just passed a link to:
[Scala slick query where in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14064382/scala-slick-query-where-in-list)